# how to create multiple statements lambda expression from string

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression, statements

we have some user data,At some point ,We want to modify the user data  values for users who meet some criteria.
For Example:when user online time >100 hours,we can add bonus he 10 Gold coins.

Now I'm using the following code to make adjustments to the data

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public void UserBounds(List<userdata> DataList)
{

    DataList.Where(p => p.Onlinetime > 100).Select(x =>
            {
                x.Bound = x.Bound + 10;
                return x;
            }).ToList();

    DataList.Where(p => p.isFirstLogin).Select(x =>
            {
                x.Bound = x.Bound + 1;
                return x;
            }).ToList();
}
```

Then the criteria are much higher now, i want to use string expression to perform these actions,I put filters and rewards on the List.like sql where and update  syntax . 
for example
|---------------------|------------------|
|    　　  Filter 　　        |     Bounds 　　      |
|---------------------|------------------|
| Onlinetime >100 　    | Bound = Bound + 10      |
|-----------------------|--------------------|
| isFirstLogin    　　    | Bound = Bound + 5       |
|-----------------------|--------------------|

now i use the system.linq.dynamic,it can use the filter string as where expression,but how can i generate the  the Expression statements  from bounds string . like 
**"Bound = Bound + 10"**,the  Expression is

```
    x =>{
          x.Bound = x.Bound + 10;
          return x;
        };
```

thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

Reminder that Linq is used for querying data, not updating data. The query can transform data into another form.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new []
    {
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = true , OnlineTime =   0, Bound = 0  }, // bound + 5
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = true , OnlineTime = 101, Bound = 0  }, // bound + 15
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = false, OnlineTime =  50, Bound = 10 }, // bound + 0
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = false, OnlineTime = 200, Bound = 25 }, // bound + 10
    };

    var query = data
        .Select(x =>
            {
                x.Bound += 
                    x.IsFirstLogin && x.OnlineTime > 100 ? 15 :
                    x.IsFirstLogin ? 5 :
                    x.OnlineTime > 100 ? 10 : 0;
                return x;
            }
        )
        .Dump() // remove this line if not in LinqPad
    ;
}

public class Data
{
    public bool IsFirstLogin { get; set; }
    public int OnlineTime { get; set; }
    public int Bound { get; set; }
}
```

Result in LinqPad:
[image]

Alternate solution, add 2 unmapped property to the class.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new []
    {
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = true , OnlineTime =   0, Bound = 0  }, // bound + 5
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = true , OnlineTime = 101, Bound = 0  }, // bound + 15
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = false, OnlineTime =  50, Bound = 10 }, // bound + 0
        new Data { IsFirstLogin = false, OnlineTime = 200, Bound = 25 }, // bound + 10
    };

    var query = data
        .Select(x =>
            {
                x.Bound += x.GetBoundIsFirstLogin + x.GetBoundOnlineTime;
                return x;
            }
        )
        .Dump() // remove this line if not in LinqPad
    ;
}

public class Data
{
    public bool IsFirstLogin { get; set; }
    public int OnlineTime { get; set; }
    public int Bound { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int GetBoundIsFirstLogin => IsFirstLogin ? 5 : 0;
    [NotMapped]
    public int GetBoundOnlineTime => OnlineTime > 100 ? 10 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Han.
1.Linq can update the list's item value,like this

```
var datas = data.ToList();

datas.Select(p => {
    p.Bound=p.Bound+100;
    return p;
}).ToList();

datas.Dump();
```

[LinqPad test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guicF.jpg)

2.the key isn't Update the list data, in my datas, I need to change the results of the data according to many conditions, so the code-defined conditions are not applicable, only the corresponding expressions can be generated dynamically, and then use this expression to update the data,the key is convert the string into an lambda Expression.
like convert  **"Bound=Bound+10"** to expression

```
x=>{x.Bound = x.Bound + 10;
return x;}
```

3.I think maybe use the `Expression<Action<data>> or Expression<Action<data,data>>` ,
 But I haven't found a way to  test it.